# How to achieve this navigation style in wordpress navigation

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation

I was wondering how to achieve this navigation style in WordPress. The menu structure is like this --

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <a href="index.php">
       Home
       <span>
         MAIN PAGE
       </span>
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want your menu to be dynamically generated by wordpress? If not, you can simply add your HTML code to `header.php` file in you template's folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Appearance » Menus. Click on Screen Options button at top right corner of the page. Check the Descriptions box from it.

This will allow you to display the description of the menu and you can customize it as per HTML above.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy to achieve this menu style in wordpress navigation by enabling "menu description" from screen options.
You can find brief information [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-menu-descriptions-in-your-wordpress-themes/).